# C# Casting the Foreach value to one of it's properties

Tags: c#, oop, foreach

I'm not sure that title conveys my meaning, please change it if you can better define this question in a sentence.

I'd like to iterate through a collection of T, but instead of working with the (T)object, I want to retrieve (T)object.SomeProperty.

How I can do it:

```
List<Car> _cars;
FillList(_cars);

foreach (Car car in _cars)
{
    Windshield ws = car.Windshield;

    ws.DoWorkA();
    ws.DoWorkB();
    ws.DoWorkC();
}
```

What I'd love to do:

```
List<Car> _cars;
FillList(_cars);

foreach (Car car in _cars using ws as Windshield = car.Windshield)
{
    ws.DoWorkA();
    ws.DoWorkB();
    ws.DoWorkC();
}
```

Any way to become an even lazier programmer?

Comment: Your second method is longer than your first.  Not sure how lazy that is.

Comment: Yeah, I know, and I considered changing the last sentence to remove lazy, but I was too lazy to do so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use LINQ and select:

```
foreach (Windshield ws in _cars.Select(car => car.Windshield))
{
    ws.DoWorkA();
    ws.DoWorkB();
    ws.DoWorkC();
}
```

Comment: Looping the collection to build a new collection to loop through IMO is not the best for performance...

Comment: I thought LINQ will just enumerate through without building a whole new collection (unless you explicitly call something like ToList())

Comment: It won't create a new collection. LINQ uses deferred execution. Because there is no `ToList` or `ToArray` in the code it will just do "one" foreach and yield one Windshield in each step.

Comment: Thanks Nemesv, that's exactly what I was hoping for. In addition to providing direct access to the Windshield, does this also restrict the loop from accessing the Car object itself?

Comment: @Michael with this construct inside the `foreach` you cannot access the `car` objects. If you want to access also the car object you are better with your original code without the `select`.

Comment: @nemesv Actually, that is what I was hoping for :) Thanks again.

Comment: It's a good answer, yet - if you compare both code samples, there is not a word less to type, and personally i can read the one without LINQ faster. That shouldn't make your answer lesser, but i think LINQ is sometimes used too commonly.

Answer (score 1):

use Linq:

```
List<Car> _cars; 
FillList(_cars);  
foreach (Windshield ws in _cars.Select(c=>c.Windshield) {
         ws.DoWorkA();
         ws.DoWorkB();
         ws.DoWorkC(); 
    }
```